# Django uploading file - permission denied

Tags: django, apache, file-upload

I've tried everything that i've found regarding this problem, but nothing helped me to solve this issue.

When i try to upload something on my web site i get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/****/www/site.com/media/news/some_file.pdf'
```

ls -l media gives me next:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 11 23:13 news
```

so permissions are OK.

Everything was working well with development server but now in production i just cant upload anything.

How to fix this?

Comment: when you `su` as www-data, can you write in this folder ?

Comment: Is your django instance running under `www-data`?

Comment: I dont know how to check that. I'm using putty, and i can log in on my server as 'root' and as one user who can see only www folder and it's subfolders. I dont know how to log in as www-data user so i could check what you suggested guys..

Comment: OK, i got it! `su - www-data` and then i tried `date > date.txt` in media folder and it created file, so www-data user can write in media folder. But i don't know how to check if django is running under www-data?

Answer (score 1):

As a noob for linux/apache I didn't know that default user for apache in CentOS (that i'm running on my server) is `apache` and not `www-data`.

**So `chown -R apache:apache media` did the trick.**

In last few days i've searched a bunch of topics regarding this problem and none of them did mention that there's other default user but www-data. It looks like that most of users are runing Ubuntu as everyone is talking about www-data.